# Blender edit mode will only let it move stuff at intervals

Tags: animation

I am new to blender and using Blender in 2D. I was just in edit mode moving things around, and then it would only let me move things at certain intervals. To clarify, I could move things, but it would only let me move it by a certain amount, no more, no less
[image: From here]
From here[image: to here]
To here

Answer (score 0):

Please check, that snapping is turned off.

Comment: Thanks it worked